# How to show blinking browser window

Tags: macos, dock, window-manager

Guys, help, please. I don't know what to do.

I'm using a web application for my job. This is interactive web chat. It opens in new window and uses tab header blinking to notify when new messages are coming. Problem is that I can't see windows of one app in dock. For example, I'm Google Chrome user. Each window of this chat opens in new browser's window, and I can see one icon only in the dock. So I can't to watch the window where chat is, and if message will come - I can't to see the notification about this. This thing can be named as "Dock do grouping windows of one app and doesn't show them". In Windows wen can disable this feature and all windows are available at the panel without grouping.

What can I do? Maybe there are some programs as HyperDock, which expands dock's functionality?

Comment: I know about holding Chrome's icon, so options will be shown. And there are all windows. But it isn't useful - would be cool if all Chrome's windows were seen as icons. Or maybe some popup would raising by default, or when I put the cursor on the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, Safari does what I need with some differences.